# Store command to file

Tags: bash

I'd like to create a script A which creates a script B. Script B creates a directory. So I created a file with this content, grant x permission to it, then execute it. Unfortunately it doesn't run as I expect. It makes directory first then create an empty file. Why?

```
#!/bin/bash
batch=`mkdir /home/hieund/bpl`
echo $batch > newfile
```

Update:
After trying your solution, I have:

```
#!/bin/bash
$myPath=$HOME/bpl
batch='mkdir ' $myPath
echo $batch > newfile
```

It doesn't work as well. Same unexpected behavior.

Update:

```
#!/bin/bash
$myPath=$HOME/bpl
batch="mkdir $myPath"
echo $batch > newfile
```

It doesn't work too. Same unexpected behavior.

```
bash: /home/hieund/bpl=/home/hieund/bpl: No such file or directory
```

Comment: bash is not perl: whoen you assign a variable, there is no dollar sign on the left-side: `myPath=$HOME/bpl`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It makes a directory at the moment of assignment, because you said this with "command substitution"

```
batch=`mkdir /home/hieund/bpl`
```

The flow of execution

1. `mkdir /home/...` - creates the directory - because of backticks - command substitution
2. the `mkdir` returns nothing, therefore
3. the assignment is like `batch=` (it assigns nothing)
4. the `echo $batch` echoes the "nothing" so: `echo > newfile`

you should to use

```
batch='mkdir /home/hieund/bpl'
```

for embedding variable use double quotes

```
batch="mkdir $myPath"
```

You always can use the `bash -x script` - to show what is executing. E.g. having a script `myscript.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
MYDIR="./somedir"
batch="mkdir $MYDIR"
echo "$batch" > newfile
```

the command

```
bash -x myscript.sh
```

will show the execution of command and arguments. (note, not shown redirections)

```
+ MYDIR=./somedir
+ batch='mkdir ./somedir'
+ echo 'mkdir ./somedir'
```

One comment: You should generally assign things to variables with double quotes, because you can avoid problems with spaces. Note

```
myvar=$VAR/some
```

and

```
myvar="$VAR/some"
```

makes a big difference when the `$VAR` contains spaces.

Comment: but I can't embed variable to it >> batch='mkdir $myPath'. It generates error "... No such file or directory"

Comment: It doesn't work. See my update. I store the path in variable.

Comment: read EXACTLY the answer! You can't use `$myPath=$HOME/bpl` you should use `myPath=$HOME/bpl` (without the sigil at the start) - you REALLY should try, the `bash -x` - it will show you, where you makes mistakes. My answer is correct :) :)

Answer (score 0):

Because backticks are not used for strings.

```
batch="mkdir /home/hieund/bpl"
```